# C# custom attribute naming

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, attributes

I have a custom Attribute class that I defined as:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Field | AttributeTargets.Property)]
public sealed class MyCustomAttribute : System.Attribute
{
    ...
}
```

From the microsoft website:

> By convention, the name of the
>   attribute class ends with the word
>   Attribute. While not required, this
>   convention is recommended for
>   readability. When the attribute is
>   applied, the inclusion of the word
>   Attribute is optional.

So, the attribute can be use by either

```
[MyCustom()]
```

or

```
[MyCustomAttribute()]
```

My question to you all, is if anyone has experienced any problems with using the abbreviated version of the name vs the full name?  I am running 4.0 framework.

Thanks!

Comment: What kind of problems? The question is kind of open-ended…

Comment: You should be able to call `[MyCustom]` without any problems (and without any parentheses for that matter :) Are you have problems then? Any error messages?

Comment: nope! I think its like asking _"have you had problems not starting interfaces names with a I?"_ Its been working fine for years...

Comment: Yes, it is... I was having run time issues and how the attribute was being called was the only change that I noticed (but there is likely something else).  One reason for my concern was using the GetCustomAttribute Assembly method.  

But it seems like the overwhelming reply is that it works perfectly.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No problems.

Underneath in compiled IL the name always has Attribute appended to it (the full type name).

Based on [ECMA-334](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST-WITHDRAWN/ECMA-334,%203rd%20edition,%20June%202005.pdf) (C# spec) 24.2, the resolution is done first by exact match, then by appending "Attribute" to the name given in [].  Additionally, if there is a conflict (ex: MyAttribute, and MyAttributeAttribute) a compile time error is generated when "MyAttribute" would be used.

Comment: I think at least for the version sharplab is using this seems to have changed or am I doing something wrong?

https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LglgNgPgAgTARgLACgYGYAE9MGFMDeqmJmxpG2cmA4gE4CmDwYAdgOaYiYCCwwdMACMArsAaEAvuRIzMAbXpMWHALpzKMACyYAKgwDOwXBACGBgwAoAlITnSUkoA==

Answer (score 9):

It should be fine... I'd just advise you not to introduce two attributes with names only differing by the number of Attribute suffixes:

```
public class FooAttribute : Attribute { }

public class FooAttributeAttribute : Attribute { }

[FooAttribute] // Could be either!
```

I *suspect* the exact match would win here, but please don't introduce the ambiguity in the first place. (I haven't checked the spec.)

Answer (score 1):

Nope. Easy as pie!

Also, you can use it without the empty `()` parentheses

Answer (score 0):

In general, you shouldn't hit any problems. The C# compiler is smart enough to resolve it to the proper type in either case.